# ¿Problema al generar una en SQL server para mostrarlas en un xtraReport?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Al generar la consulta para las fechas en `SQL` el resultado es el correcto, pero al meterlo en consultas separadas, cuando quiero verlo en el `XtraReport` solo me muestra la primera, mi duda es ¿cómo podría solucionar este problema? ya sea desde la consulta o el `XtraReport`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AsistenciaDeMaestros] 
(@datFechaInicial DATE,
 @datFechaFinal DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WHILE(@datFechaInicial<=@datFechaFinal)
    BEGIN

IF ((DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=1) OR(DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=2)OR (DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=3)OR
(DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=4)OR(DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=5))

BEGIN

  SELECT strDia=(DATENAME(dw, @datFechaInicial)),strFecha=(@datFechaInicial)

END

    SET @datFechaInicial=DATEADD(day, 1, @datFechaInicial)
END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

una solución puede ser creando una tabla temporal, añadiendo las filas allí y luego haciendo un solo select. El problema del procedimiento actual es que hace una select por cada fecha.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AsistenciaDeMaestros] 
    (@datFechaInicial DATE,
     @datFechaFinal DATE
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        create table ##temporal(strDia  nvarchar(15),strFecha smalldatetime )

        WHILE(@datFechaInicial<=@datFechaFinal)
        BEGIN

    IF ((DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=1) OR(DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=2)OR (DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=3)OR
    (DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=4)OR(DATEPART(dw,@datFechaInicial)=5))

    BEGIN

       insert into ##temporal values (DATENAME(dw, @datFechaInicial), @datFechaInicial)

    END

        SET @datFechaInicial=DATEADD(day, 1, @datFechaInicial)
    END

        select * from ##temporal
    END
```

Comment: O gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Pero eso solo funciona por una vez, por que cuando inserte otra fecha me da error